# Help command documentation explanation

Tags: command-line, bash, cd-command, helpfile

Running `help cd` gives:

```
The variable CDPATH defines the search path for the directory containing
DIR. Alternative directory names in CDPATH are separated by a colon (:).
A null directory name is the same as the current directory. If DIR begins
with a slash (/), then CDPATH is not used.
```

Can anyone explain this a little more, with some examples:

- CDPATH are separated by a colon (:)
- A null directory name is the same as the current directory.
- If DIR begins with a slash (/), then CDPATH is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Explaining "these a little more" needs an explanation of what "these" are, and what questions you have. I'll try.

If the `cd` shell builtin doesn't see the target directory in the current directory, it consults `CDPATH`. If the target directory is absolute (begins with the root directory, `/`), `CDPATH` is not used.

`CDPATH` is a colon-separated list of directories, e.g.

```
CDPATH="/home/walt/first:/usr/local/bin:/home/walt"
```

I could then `cd  Documents`, no matter what my current directory happens to be.

When dealing with "colon-separated" lists (`PATH` is one example) I use Stephen Collyer's bash_path_funcs, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3768
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3935

The `addpath` function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there in the first place. `delpath -n` deletes all non-existent directories from a path. `listpath` lists a path.

You can get the `pathfunc.tgz` file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz

Comment: In your example, the last path in CDPATH  should not be "......:/home/walt/Documents", but rather "......:/home/walt". The argument in "cd Documents" is appended to each of the paths in CDPATH and the first match is taken. 
By the way, cd is smart enough to know it has to add a "/" between the path and Documents.

Comment: @knu Fixed, thank you.

Comment: @waltinator The OP is blindly pasting `/home/walt` to 2 new questions without changing it to fit their username. You might want to clarify that part