# CDPATH help documentation—3

Tags: command-line, bash

`man bash` says:

> The variable CDPATH defines the search path for the directory containing DIR. Alternative directory names in CDPATH are separated by a colon (`:`).

> A null directory name is the same as the current directory. If DIR begins with a slash (`/`), then CDPATH is not used.

What is a “DIR”?

---

CDPATH is not a command, right ? It’s the variable name of a search path..

---

If DIR begins with a slash (`/`), then CDPATH is not used.

```
CDPATH="/home/walt/first:/usr/local/bin:/home/walt"
```

But in this CDPATH example it  begins with a (`/`)..

---

What is a null directory name?

---

```
CDPATH="/home/walt/first:/usr/local/bin:/home/walt"
```

In the example above is that what I have to write on the terminal?

---

If I write `CDPATH=`  on the terminal it returns nothing...

Comment: You have asked 3 questions about CDPATH now. Your first one, https://askubuntu.com/q/1501725/1004020 was answered. Your second one, https://askubuntu.com/q/1502884/1004020 was not answered yet. It may be too soon for you to post a third question instead of editing your second question. But anyway, I think I can try to answer this one.

Comment: You have asked 3 question without accepting answers. 1 question were answered by someone else, and 2 were by me. Please accept an answer to each question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

## What is a “DIR”?

If you look at where you quoted that line from in `man bash` you would see it is defined on the line above (***emphasis*** mine):

> cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [***dir***]
>
> Change  the  current  directory  to dir.  if dir is not supplied, the value of the HOME shell variable is the default.  The variable CDPATH defines the search path for the directory containing dir:

So it means that dir is the thing you are trying to `cd` into.

## CDPATH is not a command, right ? It’s the variable name of a search path..

Correct.

## If DIR begins with a slash (/), then CDPATH is not used. [...] But in this CDPATH example it begins with a (/)..

No, it's not talking about the `/` inside `CDPATH="/home/walt/first:/usr/local/bin:/home/walt"`. It's talking about the `/` in examples like `cd /usr`.

## What is a null directory name?

A null directory name is an empty string. Consider the example `CDPATH="home/walt/first::/home/walt"`. The null directory name is the empty thing between the colons (`::`) in the middle.

## In the example above (`CDPATH="/home/walt/first:/usr/local/bin:/home/walt"`) is that what I have to write on the terminal?

Yes, that looks like it would work.

## If I write CDPATH= on the terminal it returns nothing..

Yes, it's not supposed to return anything. Variable assignments in bash don't produce any terminal output. `CDPATH="/home/walt/first:/usr/local/bin:/home/walt"` assigns the value `/home/walt/first:/usr/local/bin:/home/walt` to the variable `CDPATH`.